# Send extra parameters with ajax chosen

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, cakephp

I'm currently using the chosen JQuery plugin :
http://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/

with this complement (to add an Ajax request) :
https://github.com/meltingice/ajax-chosen

I would like to know if anyone has ever been able to send extra parameters to the ajax function.
For now it only sends the letters in the input, but I would like to send an extra id.
Here's what i'm doing:

```
    $("#mySelect").ajaxChosen({
    minTermLength: 2,
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Orders/ajax_getBundleItems",
    dataType: "json",
    error: onItemChosenFail
    },
    function (data)
    {
        var terms = {};

        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            terms[i] = val;
        });
        return terms;
    });
```

I'm using the CakePHP Framework, here's my ajax function:

```
    public function ajax_getBundleItems($term = null) {
            $this->layout = false;
            echo "<pre>";
            var_dump($this->request->data);
            var_dump($this->params['url']['term']);
            echo "</pre>";
      }
```

**$this->params['url']['term']** gives me the letters in the input, and I would like **$this->request->data** to be an id.

Regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can pass it in url parameter like this:

```
var id = 123;

    $("#mySelect").ajaxChosen({
    minTermLength: 2,
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Orders/ajax_getBundleItems?Id="+id,
    dataType: "json",
    error: onItemChosenFail
    },
    function (data)
    {
        var terms = {};

        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            terms[i] = val;
        });
        return terms;
    });
```

or

```
var MyId = 23;

$("#mySelect").ajaxChosen({
    minTermLength: 2,
    type: "GET",
    url: "/Orders/ajax_getBundleItems",
    dataType: "json",
    data: { id:MyId },
    error: onItemChosenFail
    },
    function (data)
    {
        var terms = {};

        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            terms[i] = val;
        });
        return terms;
    });
```

you can pass here you Id from some variable

Comment: This could work only if the id doesn't change. I would like to send a specific id each time the user press some letters.

Comment: you can pass a variable as well here

Comment: Is there a way I could change the data at any moment ? Let's say I have a checkbox, when someone click it, it triggers the click event that could modify the data set in the chosen. Is it possible ?

Comment: yes i think you have reininitilize chosen make a function and just call it there

Comment: I up voted, but this solution don't work for me. Even if the variable value has changed, the function always calls with the first parameter ever set.
Even if i reinitialize the function, re-assigning it, it keeps the initial value.

Answer (score 0):

This is the actual answer, using the BeforeSend option:

```
$('select[name=element_id]', '#f-load-tc').ajaxChosen({
        type: 'GET',
        url: 'dynamic_url',
        dataType: 'json',
        afterTypeDelay: 300,
        allow_single_deselect: true,
        no_results_text: "No results matched",
        beforeSend: function(xhr, opts) {
            opts.url += '&category_id='+$category.val();
        },
    },
    function (data) {
        console.log(data);
        var terms = {};
        $.each(data, function (i, val) {
            terms[i] = val;
        });

        return terms;
    });
```